# Two versions of invariance of domain theorem?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

While reading about [Invariance of Domain Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), I noted that there are two common version of it, one saying that $f(U)$ is open, while another saying that $f$ is a homeomorphism (and sometimes both of these, like in the wikipedia link).

But I only saw proofs ([1](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/) and [2](http://pi.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/872s07/lecnotes/slides.from.class/cls26--invariance.domain.pdf)) for $f(U)$ being open, does this imply $f$ being an homeomorphism? And if it does, how?

Regarding proof [1](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/), I have two more questions, if possible:

1. Why does he say that it will be enough to prove that $f(0)$ is in the interior of $f(B^n)$? $\,\,\,$ i.e. why does [theorem #5](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/#again) imply [theorem #2](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/#invariance) (invariance of domain)? What if $0\notin U$, how can it still assist us?
2. We know that $f^{-1}: f(B^n) \rightarrow B^n$ is continuous, but why can we extend it to a continuous $G:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$? As far as I understand it, [Tietze's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) can be used on a function $h:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is closed, but in here $f(B^n)$ is not closed and we are working with $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so how comes this theorem can be used in here?

Comment: A continuous injective map is a homeomorphism to its image if and only if it is open.

Comment: @DanielFischer, but in here we didn't show that $f$ is an open map, we simply showed that $f(U)$ is open.

Comment: Let $V$ be any (non-empty, to have something to show) open subset of $U$. Consider the restriction $g = f\lvert_V$. $g$ satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem, hence $g(V)$ is open.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Any topological embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image so the continuous injective map needn't be open. Openness is sufficient, but not necessary. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user87690 Yeah, I was thinking of the situation here, where we already know that the image is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or whichever manifold is under consideration). In general, it's indeed only "open as a map to its image".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I only saw proofs for $f(U)$ being open, does this imply $f$ being an homeomorphism? And if it does, how?

Yes, as Daniel Fischer answered in the comments. Restricting the codomain of an injective map to its image yields a bijection. If $V$ is any open subset of $U$, then the pair $(V, f\rvert_V)$ also satisfies the hypothesis of the "open" version of the theorem, so $f(V)$ is open. This shows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

> 1. Why does he say that it will be enough to prove that $f(0)$ is in the interior of $f(B^n)$? $\,\,\,$ i.e. why does theorem #5 imply theorem #2 (invariance of domain)? What if $0\notin U$, how can it still assist us?

It seems that you may be a bit confused by the notational overload on $f$. Note that $f$ refers to distinct, unrelated maps in Theorems 2 and 5 (different domains, for one thing).

Here's a hint: To prove Theorem 2, it suffices to show that for each $x \in U$, we have $f(x) \in \operatorname{int} f(U)$. So for each $x \in U$, try to find a continuous injective map $g_x \colon B^n \to \mathbb R^n$ (note that $g_x$ satisfies the hypothesis of Theorem 5) that will help you do exactly that.

> 2. We know that $f^{-1}: f(B^n) \rightarrow B^n$ is continuous, but why can we extend it to a continuous $G:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$? As far as I understand it, Tietze's extension theorem can be used on a function $h:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is closed, but in here $f(B^n)$ is not closed and we are working with $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so how comes this theorem can be used in here?

The set $f(B^n)$ is actually closed. Perhaps you were under the impression as I was that $B^n$ refers to the open unit ball, but in fact, Tao defines $B^n$ as the closed unit ball at the outset (in the statement of Theorem 1). As $f$ is continuous, $f(B^n)$ is compact, hence closed.

We can then use the fact that a map into a product space is continuous iff each of its component maps is continuous. Break $f^{-1}$ into its component functions $(f^{-1})_i \colon f(B^n) \to \mathbb R$, extend by Tietze to $G_i \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, then take $G := (G_1, \dotsc, G_n)$.

Comment: I'm still trying to find such a $g_x: B^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, but I find it hard to see what function should I be searching for? After all, I have any $u\in U$ and I need to map to $B^n$, but $Dom(g_x) = B^n$ and not the range!

Comment: I mean, $Dom(g_x) = B^n$, when, if I understood you correctly, we would like that $g_x: U \rightarrow B^n$, right?

Comment: I meant it when I said that $g_x$ is $U \to B^n$. Note that the restriction of $f$ to any subset of $U$ is still continuous and injective. So if there is a homeomorphism $h$ from $B^n$ to some $A \subseteq U$ such that $h(0) = x$, then we may take $g_x = f\rvert_A \circ h$.

Comment: Thanks, got it!
But regarding my 2nd question - we can use tietze's theorem, thus we have a continuous function $G:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that  it extends $f^{-1}$, but why does it have a zero on $f(B^n)$? and assuming it does, why is it necessarily at $f(0)$?

Comment: $f(0) \in f(B^n)$ and $G(f(0)) = f^{-1}(f(0)) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! another thing - Tao says that "$P$ does not vanish on $\Sigma_1$", but I dont understand what does he mean by this? What is a "vanishing" function?

Comment: @Eric_ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vanishing.html